# grep on any cell in a data.frame

Tags: regex, r, screen-scraping

A simple "is there a better way" question. I want to find if any cell in a data.frame contains the sub-string I'm looking for:

```
d=data.frame(V1=c("xxx","yyy","zzz"), V2=c(NA,"ewruinwe",NA))
grepl("ruin",d[2,2])  #TRUE
grepl("ruin",d)  #FALSE FALSE
any(grepl("ruin",as.character(as.matrix(d))))   #TRUE
```

The last line does what I want, but it looks so ugly I'm wondering if I'm missing something simpler.

Background: `d` is one of the elements in `t=readHTMLTable(url)` (XML package). I was doing the d[2,2] approach, to check for an error message, and just discovered the website sometimes add another row to the HTML table, pushing the error message I was looking for to another cell.

UPDATE: so, it seems the two choices (thanks to mathematical.coffee and Roman Luštrik) are:

```
any(grepl("ruin",as.matrix(d)))
any(apply(d, 2, function(x) grepl("ruin", x)))
```

Comment: For what it's worth, you don't have to do the `as.character` after casting to `as.matrix`, because R does that already. i.e. `any(grepl('ruin',as.matrix(d),ignore.case=T))`. I reckon it's about as slick as you'll get. You could use `apply` and friends but that just looks worse: `any(apply(d,1,function(x)grepl("ruin",x,ignore.case=T)))`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about this?

```
d=data.frame(V1=c("xxx","yyy","zzz"), V2=c(NA,"ewruinwe",NA))
apply(d, c(1,2), function(x) grepl("ruin", x))
        V1    V2
[1,] FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE  TRUE
[3,] FALSE FALSE
```

As noted in the comments "2" does the same as "c(1,2)". Then to give a single boolean value:

```
any(apply(d, 2, function(x) grepl("ruin", x)))
[1] TRUE
```